# python package whoosh- Nameerror: name 'unicode' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, whoosh

I'm New at programming. Need help. I tried to use python package whooshalchemy but i get a NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined. I dont understand the error. I really need help.

```
 @app.route('/search', methods =['GET','POST'])
 def search():
    if request.method=='POST':
        result_dict={}
        result={}
        search = request.form['search']
        result_dict = Student.query.whoosh_search(search).all()
        for var in result_dict:
            print(var.name)
        #print(result)
        return json.dumps(result)
    else:
        search = ''
    return render_template("test.html")
```

**The tracebackerror:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
  packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
 packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_except
ion
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch
_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_e
xception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch
_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_requ
est
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\Desktop\python prog\test\test.py", line 32, in 
search
    result_dict = Student.query.whoosh_search(search).all()
  File "C:\Users\Jeminah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask_whooshalchemy.py", line 103, in whoo
sh_search
    if not isinstance(query, unicode):
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

I dont know what's the unicode is all about. I really need help

Comment: Seems the package was written for Python 2.x but you are using Python 3.x. Probably whoosh isn't the source of the error (or you version is too old), it supports 3.x. You should post the complete error traceback.

Comment: I posted the traceback error

Comment: Your version of Flask-WhooshAlchemy seems to be too old. After a quick look the current code on GitHub seems to address this problem.